# Easy proof that $\exp{Xt} = I \Rightarrow X = 0$

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, exponential-function

> Let $X\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and $I$ is identity matrix , than if:
>   $$
> \forall t\in \mathbb{R}\quad e^{Xt} = I
> $$
>   than
>   $$
> X = 0.
> $$

I'm looking for short and slick proof of this statement.

The only way I can think of to prove this is take Jordan normal form of $X = SJS^{-1}$. $J$ can be writen as $J = D+N$ where $D$ is diagonal and $N$ nillpotent(those ones on superdiagonal) and $DN = ND$ so $e^{D+N} = e^D e^N$.

So we want to show that if $e^{(D+N)t} = I$ than $D=N=0$. Because $J$ is block diagonal we can work on those blocks separately. So we can assume that $D = \lambda I$ and $N$ is zero or has ones everywhere on superdiagonal.

If I'm right than for nonzero $N$ we have
$$
(e^{Nt})_{ij} = \frac{t^{j-i}}{(j-i)!} \qquad i\leq j
$$
zero everywhere else.

If $N$ is nonzero than:
$$
e^{(D+N)t}_{ij} = e^{\lambda t} \frac{t^{j-i}}{(j-i)!}  \qquad i\leq j
$$

So this would have to hold
$$
e^{\lambda t} \frac{t^{j-i}}{(j-i)!} = \delta_{ij} \qquad i\leq j
$$
That is not possible thus $N$ has to be zero.

If $N$ is zero than we get $e^{\lambda t} = 1$. So $\lambda = 0$.

I don't like this proof, there has to be simpler one.

Comment: Typo :D, fixed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{tX} = X e^{tX},$$

so if $e^{tX} \equiv I$, evaluating the derivative at $t = 0$ yields

$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{tX}\bigl\lvert_{t=0} = X = 0.$$

Comment: Aw snap, how I couldn't see that?!. Thank you, very nice!